# Check whether a table column has any value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have model named `shirt` which has a field named `fabric`, 
In the controller  I have;

```
@fabrics = Shirt.uniq.pluck(:fabric)
```

On the view I would like to display a `<div>...</div>` but only if the `fabric` column of the `shirts` table contains at least one value. I have tried:

```
<% if @fabrics != nil %>
  <div>
    ...
  </div>
<% end %>
```

But even when the whole column has no value,  the `<div>` is still visible. I have also tried with

`<%if @fabrics != blank %>` with no success.
How can I check whether the column is not empty before rendering the div?

Comment: what do you get from the console from: `@fabrics = Shirt.uniq.pluck(:fabric)`? and `@fabrics = Shirt.uniq.pluck(:fabric).class`?

Comment: does uniq work on the class Shirt ? try it on console and show the output.

Comment: @Miotsu I am using `@fabrics` on the same view to display all the fabrics and it is working.

Comment: that doesn't answer my question :)

Comment: If I read your question correctly, `<% Shirt.any? { |s| !s.fabric.nil? } %>` would suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in controller

```
@fabrics = Shirt.uniq.pluck(:fabric).reject { |f| f.nil? || f.empty? }
```

Comment: Thanks this worked, would you please explain what the `.reject` did.

Comment: Returns a new array containing the items in self for which the block is not true(see more here http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/reject)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
<% unless @fabrics.blank? %>
```

Comment: I have used @Thaha answer on the controller and this answer on the view and it worked. Thanks Pierre.

Answer (score 2):

`Shirt.uniq.pluck(:fabric)` returns a `Relation`. Therefore it will never be `nil`.

This `Relation` defines parts of a sql query. This says: *Give me (all|one of the) unique values of fabric in the database.* To actually run that query, you need to call a method on that relation that triggers the database call: `all`, `first`, `each`, `any?`, `blank?` ...

Through the lack of context, I do not know how you use your `Shirt` model. But I guess the query will never give you the expected answer. Because `Shirt.uniq.pluck(:fabric)` will always return something as long there is at least one row in that table. Imagine there is only one row in the table and it's `fabric` is `nil`, than `Shirt.uniq.pluck(:fabric).blank?` would determine `Shirt.uniq.pluck(:fabric)` to `[nil]`. And `[nil].blank? == false`

If you work on one specific shirt, use `@shirt.fabric.present?` If you want to know if there is at least one shirt in the db without a fabric `Shirt.where(fabric: nil).any?`

I recommend to read:

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html
- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html